# How to set the Font on an NSTextView that is bound to an object?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextview

I have an NSTextView whose object is bound to its datasource. I cannot figure out how to intervene to a) save changes, and b) set (or allow the user to set) the font. I have seen lots of questions on this on SO.

I've tried things like:

```
[[textView textStorage] setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
```

I have a `textDidChange` method - but it's not getting called...

```
-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); 
    NSTextView *textView = [notification object];

    [currentItem setValue:textView.string forKey:@"narrative"];
    [currentItem setObject:[textView string] forKey:@"narrative"];

    NSString *oldField = [currentItem objectForKey:@"narrative"];
    [currentItem setObject:[textView string] forKey:textView.string];

    [currentItem saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Revert state on save error.
            [currentItem setObject:oldField forKey:@"narrative"];
            textView.string = oldField;
        }
    }];

    [[textView textStorage] setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]];    
    [textView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}
```

I am somewhat new to Cocoa bindings, so any ideas would be appreciated..

Comment: You might consider setting up a custom class for your NSTextViews or NSTextFields which makes it convenient; posting your solution might be helpful for others as well.

Comment: I will post a solution when I find one.. promise. Thanks for the idea of a custom class.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were stating you had solved the issue in your first comment, and had essentially answered your own question.

Comment: I think I was overly optimistic .. I'll get there.

Comment: Modify the attributedString for the textView and don't touch the textStorage.  Incidentally, that is what your link does.

Comment: As this is loaded from a model through Cocoa Bindings, I could use some help figuring where to intercept the textview and change its attributes. I think if I understand where to set the attributes, I can change them accordingly.